# Unable to select dropdown menu with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am unable to select a particular element in this webpage for automation in Selenium (python).

These two fields, taken from the webpage, are what I'm looking for:

[image]

When I right-clicked and clicked on "inspect element," I found the following html markup (well, a subset of it):

```
<label>Client ID:</label>
<db-client-combobox default-value="vm.clientId" on-select="vm.onClientSelected(clientId)" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <db-combobox placeholder="Select a client" list="clientNames" default-value="defaultValue" on-select="onClientSelected(value)" mode="longlist" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <div class="input-group combobox dropdown">
            <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Select a client" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-model="itemSelected" ng-change="onInputKeyUp()" ng-focus="onInputFocus()" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle btn" id="combobox-list" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
<span class="caret"></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="combobox-list">
                <!-- ngIf: mode == 'longlist' -->
                <div class="sf-viewport sf-viewport-biglist real ng-scope" ng-if="mode == 'longlist'" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 300px;">
                    <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; height: 67912px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end ngIf: mode == 'longlist' -->
                <!-- ngIf: mode == 'shortlist' -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </db-combobox>
</db-client-combobox>
</div> &nbsp;
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Agent ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control js-call-type ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="vm.agentId">
</div>
```

The "Client ID" field is both a drop-down and a text field (it's up to the user to choose whether said user wants to type the Client ID or select it from a drop down menu).
The Agent ID is simply a text field to enter numbers.

I can't seem to select either in Selenium. To select the Client ID, for example, I've tried the following Python commands (separately):

```
client_id_field = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('select')
client_id_field = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")
client_id_field = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched")
client_id_field = browser.select_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/db-client-combobox/db-combobox/div/input')
client_id_field = browser.select_by_class_name('form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched')
```

Sadly, nothing seems to work, and I'm not sure why. The only other possibility I see is selecting the labels, i.e. `<label>Client ID:</label>` and then telling the interpreter to go to the next element and select that- though I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE: after following alecxe's suggestion to try inserting

```
client_id_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[. = 'Client ID:']/following-sibling::db-client-combobox")
```

I got the following error in the command line prompt:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Una
ble to find element with xpath '//label[. = 'Client ID:']/following-sibling::db-
client-combobox'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Enco
ding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"147","Content-Type":"app
lication/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:53214","User-Agent":"Python-urlli
b/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"ses
sionId\": \"d67f3550-e736-11e6-a1df-2f9c010cd01f\", \"value\": \"//label[. = 'Cl
ient ID:']/following-sibling::db-client-combobox\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed
":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","re
lative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","au
thority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]
},"urlOriginal":"/session/d67f3550-e736-11e6-a1df-2f9c010cd01f/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Something that strikes me oddly (sorry if this sounds so naive) is that the command line says `unable to find element with xpath...` and then after listing the xpath I asked for, it also lists lots of other jargon that I didn't mean to ask for. Am I not making the most out of the interpreter's debugging response?

Answer (score 1):

> The only other possibility I see is selecting the labels, i.e. Client ID: and then telling the interpreter to go to the next element and select that- though I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be.

This can be achieved with a [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
client_id_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[. = 'Client ID:']/following-sibling::db-client-combobox")
```

Then, once you have the client id box element, you can locate the inner input:

```
client_id_input = client_id_box.find_element_by_tag_name("input")
client_id_input.click()  # TODO: you might not need it, please check
client_id_input.send_keys("Test")
```

For the dropdown, you first probably need to open it up and then select the desired option:

```
client_id_box.find_element_by_id("combobox-list").click()  # open the dropdown
# TODO: select option
```

Note that, to make things more reliable and to avoid timing errors, you may need to start using [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: Thank you for your swift response, alecxe. I tried your suggestion to use the `following-sibling` axis, but I still got a strange error. I updated my question to include the error response. Would you mind checking it out? Needless to say, I'm still very new to web scraping.

Comment: @daOnlyBG sure, what if you use the `WebDriverWait` and `presence_of_element_located` expected condition? (may be a timing error)

Comment: Sure thing. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: When coding for the expected condition, the example uses `By.ID, "myDynamicElement"`. The element I'm looking for doesn't have an explicitly stated `ID`; how would you recommend I implement the condition? I was thinking to do:
`EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[. = 'Client ID:']/following-sibling::db-client-combobox"))`

Comment: @daOnlyBG ah, use the `By.XPATH` instead.

Comment: Yeah... it timed out after 60 seconds. I'm guessing it doesn't have to do with the loading time. If you'd like, we can go into a chat and I can show you more of the code. I don't think it's terribly long.

Comment: @daOnlyBG okay - do you see if this element is inside an `iframe`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134421/discussion-between-daonlybg-and-alecxe).